# When I change vertical size of XNA game window to minimum, it throws ObjectDisposedException for spritebatch, why?

Tags: c#, xna, window, spritebatch

When I resize the game window and the viewport's height becomes 0, GC disposes of spritebatch, I think. Is this what happens? How do I prevent this?

Comment: Now I know how to prevent this, still it would be interesting to know how spritebatch gets disposed of.

Comment: Just to be clear, the GC doesn't dispose of the `SpriteBatch`. I just ran a little test and it seems that XNA is *supposed* to prevent resizing down to zero (weird that it doesn't for you). Resizing can cause the graphics device (and all its resources) to be re-initialized. If it fails to re-initialise because the size of the window is zero, then `SpriteBatch` ends up in more-or-less the same state it would be in if it were disposed.

Comment: I tried this on an empty new project and resizing causes this error, but none of my older projects behave like that. Well, I guess there's really no need to resize to zero, so I could set minimum size like in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Form gameForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
gameForm.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
```

Short and sweet!

Comment: Nice. But this requires `using System.Windows.Forms;` or `using Forms = System.Windows.Forms;` to avoid unwanted ambiguity.

Comment: Still, this may not work for all cases with the same values, it has to be compensated for the size of window theme borders. Guess this should be done using `form.ClientArea`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and some quick debugging shows that XNA calls UnloadContent and then LoadContent again to reinitialise resources; my guess it it loses the GraphicsDevice or something, hence the reload.

Creating things pertaining to the GraphicsDevice in LoadContent solves this problem.

Now, for this particular case, setting a minimum size is a good idea, but I don't know if this is a portable solution between Xbox and Windows. However, there might be other situations in which something similar occurs, where UnloadContent is called, so it's probably best to adhere to this practice.