# Is it possible to restore a GraphicsDevice if something goes wrong with it?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm having [this nasty problem with my game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225701/how-to-prevent-graphicsdevice-from-being-disposed-when-applying-new-settings) randomly crashing when changing the game window size, and I can't seem to find the source of the issue, so I'd like to try and approach this from another angle.

Say the `GraphicsDevice` got disposed somehow. Can I recreate it or return it to its working state, so the game could continue running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

That instance is coupled to so many things, that using a new one after that's been disposed in its life cycle would be pratically reimplementing XNA. If you're trying to use it and it's been disposed, you're doing something very wrong. And you can't make things right by fixing a small implementation error with a huge design and project error.

For your own good, try to figure out what you've done wrong, and fix that instead. Check whether everything you're doing is being done at the right moment.

Comment: You can see the linked question for additional information on the original issue. If you can add something useful to that question, please do.

Comment: Only this: out of the three answers so far in there, two of them may be the one you're looking for (I'm not betting on the guy who's just quoting docs).